# How to merge a Generic.Collection.List and Generic.Collection.Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, lambda

i have a  Generic.Collection.List  and Generic.Collection.Dictionary like

```
List<String> MyList
Dictionary<String, List<String>> MyDictionary
```

I need to filter the `MyDictionary` based on the intes in the `MyList` i.e if an item of `MyList` is in the `value` of  `MyDictionary`, then that item will be added into `MyFilteredDictionary`.

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>> MyFilteredDictionary
```

Now i'm doing this by using `` `for-foreach `` loop, like

```
for (int l_nIndex = 0; l_nIndex < MyList.Count; l_nIndex++)
  {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, List<String>> l_objKeyValuePair in MyDictionary)
      {
         if (l_objKeyValuePair.Value.Contains(MyList[l_nIndex]) == true)
           {
             MyFilteredDictionary.Add(l_objKeyValuePair.Key, l_objKeyValuePair.Value);
             break;
            }
       }
  }
```

How to do the same using `Lambda Expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var res = MyDictionary.Where(kvp => MyList.Any(item => kvp.Value.Contains(item)))
                      .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but this will create a filtered dictionary of items based on items in another dictionary that have keys in a list...

```
    MyFilteredDictionary = MyList
        .Where(MyDictionary.ContainsKey)
        .ToDictionary(item => item, item => MyDictionary[item]);
```